# Hashmap (of strings) in grails domain Class

Tags: java, mysql, grails, hashmap

Currently I have a Grails domain class with a HashMap of strings (HashMap metadata = new HashMap().

Everything is working fine with database persistence on creation (stored as  BLOB by the way), start-up, shutdown, etc...

I have a nasty feeling that this is not okay for some reason, if that is the case why?  if not, then never mind.

Versions etc Grails 2.0, Groovy 1.8, Java 1.6, Tomcat 6 MySQL 5.latest

Comment: what is the nasty feeling? What are the reasons?

Comment: when you have nasty feeling for some reason, how could we know?

Comment: The nasty feeling probably comes from the fact that storing information in a blob makes it impossible to query, and that databases are used to be able to execute queries on the stored data.

Comment: @JBNizet hah, in this case that does not matter.  I don't have a reason for that "nasty feeling", so far no issues, just wanted to make sure that I was not overlooking any particular issues that were obvious to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that this is probably not the best practice, since you never really know how this list of strings may grow in the future.

A simple example might be that in the future, you want to know when a particular field was added, which means you would have to change your entire domain model and move the hashmap out into child domains.

From experience, it might be easier to model this as a child element with name and value properties.

This also makes it easier to write queries against this hashmap, so if you wanted to find elements that have the key 'blah', you can use the dynamic finder and related querying mechanisms.

Comment: Agreed.  In this case, the HashMap contains what could be considered more of less as Properties (although not in the same sense at all), and the domain model is not used as it would be "normally".  In this case, it looks like there would be no issues with this, thanks for letting me bounce my concerned of you guys.  I will call this answered.